# Android clazz.getConstructors() returning wrong number of constructors, only in live app

Tags: java, android, reflection, constructor

I have a class WifiScanning:

```
public class WifiScanning extends AbstractSetting {


/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 226897434530036069L;


public WifiScanning(Object valueToApply) {
    super(valueToApply, WifiScanning.class);
}

/**
 * For persistence only
 */
public WifiScanning() {
    super(null, WifiScanning.class);
}
```

As you can see, it has 2 constructors. One is for my simple persistence layer and is an empty constructor, so that newInstance() works, the other takes a single argument, which is a standard defined by my application. Other code assumes that there must be a constructor with a single argument, or it throws an exception.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param setting
 * @param ctx
 * @return
 * @throws SettingException
 */
private synchronized static AbstractSetting getOriginalSetting(AbstractSetting setting, 
        Context ctx) throws SettingException {

    Class<? extends AbstractSetting> clazz = setting.getClass();
    try {
        Constructor<?>[] constructors = clazz.getDeclaredConstructors();
        for (Constructor<?> c : constructors) {
            if(c.getParameterTypes().length == 1) {
                Object original = setting.getCurrentSettingValue(ctx);
                LOG.debug("Caching original value '"+original+"' for "+clazz.getSimpleName());
                return (AbstractSetting) c.newInstance(original);
            }
        }

        /*
         * ###################### DEBUG BLOCK ######################
         * 
         * This has been put here to work out why we are getting to this point in the code when
         * using WifiScanning.java
         */
        LOG.error("There are "+constructors.length+" constructors for "+clazz.getName()+" which we got from "+setting);
        for (Constructor<?> c : constructors) {
            if(c.getParameterTypes().length == 1) {
                LOG.debug("Found the consructor! How the hell can that be?");
            }
            else {
                LOG.error("Unusable constructor: "+c.toGenericString());
                LOG.error("From: "+c.getDeclaringClass());
                LOG.error("Modifiers:");
                LOG.error("private="+Modifier.isPrivate(c.getModifiers()));
                LOG.error("protected="+Modifier.isProtected(c.getModifiers()));
                LOG.error("public="+Modifier.isPublic(c.getModifiers()));
                LOG.error("static="+Modifier.isStatic(c.getModifiers()));

                Type[] genericParameterTypes = c.getGenericParameterTypes();
                LOG.error("Constructor has "+genericParameterTypes.length+" generic parameter types");
                for (Type type : genericParameterTypes) {
                    LOG.error("Generic parameter type: "+type.getClass().getName());
                }

                Class<?>[] parameterTypes = c.getParameterTypes();
                LOG.error("Constructor has "+parameterTypes.length+" parameters");
                for (Class<?> arg1 : parameterTypes) {
                    LOG.error("Constructor arg: "+arg1.getName());
                }
            }
        }
        /*
         * ###################### END DEBUG BLOCK ######################
         */

        throw new SettingException(clazz+" does not have a constructor with a single argument");
```

If you consider the code above, the DEBUG BLOCK has been added to try and understand what is going on here. If you ignore that for the moment, what you have is a block of code that gets an array of constructors from the code and iterates over them, looking for one that has a single argument. If the loop exits without finding one, an exception is thrown.

With the added exception block, the log shows:

> E/Proference: 10/7 22:28:59.917 e.b[126]: There are 1 constructors for
>   com.domloge.proference.setting.WifiScanning which we got from
>   WifiScanning "Test" [set:true|current:false|priority:1] E/Proference:
>   10/7 22:28:59.917 e.b[132]: Unusable constructor: public
>   com.domloge.proference.setting.WifiScanning() V/Proference: Purging
>   log file E/Proference: 10/7 22:28:59.918 e.b[133]: From: class
>   com.domloge.proference.setting.WifiScanning E/Proference: 10/7
>   22:28:59.919 e.b[134]: Modifiers: E/Proference: 10/7 22:28:59.919
>   e.b[135]: private=false E/Proference: 10/7 22:28:59.920 e.b[136]:
>   protected=false E/Proference: 10/7 22:28:59.920 e.b[137]: public=true
>   E/Proference: 10/7 22:28:59.920 e.b[138]: static=false E/Proference:
>   10/7 22:28:59.921 e.b[141]: Constructor has 0 generic parameter types
>   E/Proference: 10/7 22:28:59.921 e.b[147]: Constructor has 0 parameters
>   E/Proference: 10/7 22:28:59.922 j.b[270]: Could not apply

As you can see, the VM is showing the the WifiScanning class is giving *one* constructor, not 2. How can this be?

When I run the code on my personal device and various emulators this is not a problem and 2 constructors are in the array.

Problem is, when the app is distributed through the Google Play store, the array contains a single constructor. I can't debug my app when it's distributed on the Google play store, I can only view the logs.

This same principal works fine with more than 10 other classes in the app... but this one is acting up... It's as though there is a typo that I am missing which is going to be a forehead-slapping d'oh! moment when someone points out my stupid mistake...

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like perhaps ProGuard is stripping it out. If it's not used except via reflection, that'd be a strong indication that ProGuard is at fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is obviously proguard "michief".

Put the following line in proguard-project.txt

```
-keepclassmembers class * extends full-package-name.AbstractSetting {
    public protected <init>(...);
}
```

and you will have it all right.